# Cannot delete files from trash

Tags: command-line, permissions, nautilus, delete, trash

I am not able to delete 2 png files from trash. However I am able to delete other files. When i click on empty in the trash nothing is happening and when i select both the files and click on remove from trash it is showing

`Error while deleting`

`You do not have sufficient permissions to the file xxx.png` `Failed to delete the item from the trash.`

I tried the command `sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*` but no results.

When I go to `sudo nautilus` and to trash, it is showing `This location could not be displayed` `Sorry, could not display all the contents of "trash:///": Operation not supported`

command `df $(find . -type f)` (`under ~/.local/share/Trash/`) gives

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             3975532        0   3975532   0% /dev
tmpfs             800940     2076    798864   1% /run
/dev/sdb4      101265424 27146484  68931920  29% /
tmpfs            4004696   804408   3200288  21% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            4004696        0   4004696   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0          9344     9344         0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/95
/dev/loop1        100224   100224         0 100% /snap/core/10444
/dev/loop2        100224   100224         0 100% /snap/core/10577
/dev/loop4        166784   166784         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
/dev/loop3         56832    56832         0 100% /snap/core18/1944
/dev/loop5         56704    56704         0 100% /snap/core18/1932
/dev/loop6        238976   238976         0 100% /snap/gimp/322
/dev/loop7        246656   246656         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24
/dev/loop8        267008   267008         0 100% /snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/32
/dev/loop9         66432    66432         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
/dev/loop10       223232   223232         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60
/dev/loop11        31872    31872         0 100% /snap/snapd/10492
/dev/loop12        65920    65920         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1513
/dev/loop13        52352    52352         0 100% /snap/snap-store/518
/dev/loop14        36736    36736         0 100% /snap/synfigstudio/1
/dev/loop15       653824   653824         0 100% /snap/whatsdesk/20
/dev/loop16        52352    52352         0 100% /snap/snap-store/498
/dev/loop17        31872    31872         0 100% /snap/snapd/10238
/dev/sdb1          97280    33330     63950  35% /boot/efi
tmpfs             800936      104    800832   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda4      325582844  1874124 323708720   1% /media/cheran/New Volume
```

and command `ls -li $(find . -type f)` gives

```
total 12
3411035 drwx------ 2 cheran cheran 4096 Jan  3 14:48 expunged
3410985 drwx------ 2 cheran cheran 4096 Jan  3 14:48 files
3410617 drwx------ 2 cheran cheran 4096 Jan  3 14:48 info
```

Please help me with deleting these files.

Comment: Could those items have been deleted whilst another drive was mounted (eg. removable external drive?) if so, when the drive is connected, you'll be able to remove them.

Comment: No the images were not deleted before. I cannot delete even when a external drive is connected

Comment: Please add the output of the following commands to your original post `df $(find ~/.local/share/Trash/ -type f)` and `ls -li $(find ~/.local/share/Trash/ -type f)`. (You can mask your file names, but not the extensions if you want.) And, please answer also this: Can you view the contents of these files, using `less <filename>` for example?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli added

Comment: Your outputs show that `find` has found no file. Are you sure there are files under `~/.local/share/Trash/`. Please, first do  `cd ~/.local/share/Trash/` and then run the commands `df $(find . -type f)` and `ls -li $(find . -type f)`. Please delete the outputs you already pasted in to your question (they are useless) and add the new outputs from the commands I have just given.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **Trash** for your `/home` (device: `/dev/sdb4`) directory is currently empty.

However, you may have deleted files under device `/dev/sda4` which seems to be mounted at `/media/cheran/New Volume`. To check these files run:

```
find /media/cheran/New\ Volume/.Trash-* -type f
```

If you are sure that these are the files to be deleted, run:

```
rm $(find /media/cheran/New\ Volume/.Trash-* -type f)
```

Note: You may need to add `sudo` before `rm` if you do not have permission.

Comment: It worked !!!! Thanks :)
But I want to know what is that `-type f` that you have used there (I am a newbie)

Comment: `find` with option `-type f` will list only "files", not "directories". Please, do not forget to ***accept*** (click check mark on the left of) the answer.

Comment: Ooh. Thanks for the info :D . **_accepted_**.